# when I start android emulator with any configuration it is giving warning and errror

Tags: android

Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
      // I read many post and I have done all the things like ram increase and decrease,Use Host GPU uncheck,reinstall all the things 
    //But I don't understand that what is the exact problem.

Comment: What OS are you using? And what version of the SDK & ADT?

Comment: win 7 and adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219,sdk manager 21.1